# Webform custom composite

Tags: webforms

Could someone advise on how to adopt the working composite example that comes with Webform in Drupal 8?

https://www.drupal.org/node/2824714 suggests it can be done.

I've copied the example from modules/webform/modules/webform_example_composite folder. Does this need to go into the webform root folder with other example or root module folder?

I realise that the functions and iterations of webform_example_composite need to be renamed.

I also tried altering the pr-existing example that comes with Webform, without success.

Answer (score 1):

Someone very kindly posted an example https://www.drupal.org/node/2883734.
Module creator also suggested here https://www.drupal.org/node/2824714 that documentation is being updated.

Comment: Please add code from those sites, so that your answer isn't just a [link only answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259).

Comment: The answer is in the zip file zombree_webform.tar_.gz. Linking it all that can be done.